# Rate limit on Metadata API?

Tags: metadata-api, limits, migration-tool

Is there a rate limit on the Metadata API?  I seem to have caused some massive problems by using the Migration Tool a bit too frequently.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any specific rate limit to Metadata API however, overall [concurrent API limits](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm#concurrent_limits_title) is applicable for this as well.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/api_meta.pdf

Metadata API can deploy and retrieve up to 10,000 files or 400 MB at one time. If either of these limits is exceeded, the deployment or retrieval fails.

Comment: thanks.  That's not a rate limit, though, that's a each-time limit.